# Does Firebug List CSS Background Shorthand Color in the Wrong Order?

Tags: css, firebug, w3c

According to [the W3C Recommendation for the CSS background shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background), the values are `[<'background-color'> || <'background-image'> || <'background-repeat'> || <'background-attachment'> || <'background-position'>] | inherit`.

Following that recommendation, I write a declaration like this:

```
background: transparent url("/images/layout/sprite.png") repeat-y scroll right top;
```

When I inspect that element in Firebug, it lists the color part last, instead of first:

```
background: url("/images/layout/sprite.png") repeat-y scroll right top transparent;
```

Using it the Firebug way seems to work, but it doesn't follow the W3C Recommendation. I tried some Google searches, but I couldn't find any information on this. Is there some history that I am unaware of? Is it a Firebug bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#property-defs

> A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them
>   must occur, **in any order**.

So, the background values may be listed in any order.

Comment: I have been schooled. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The W3C doesn't define an order in this grammar. Background properties can be listed in any order.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this (scroll down to: Background - Shorthand property)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

> When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:
>      background-color
>      background-image
>      background-repeat
>      background-attachment
>      background-position
>   It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present are in this order.